# How can I iterate through a list of files and open each file

Tags: python, text, operating-system

I have a list of file names I am trying to iterate over each file and use a with open statement.

```
      #list of text files 
      files = ['file1.txt','file2.txt','file3.txt']
      for file in files: 
          with open(file as f ): 
             file.readlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

`with open(file as f )` should be changed to `with open(file, 'r') as f`. This specifies we want to open the file object in read mode and store this file object in read mode as the variable `f`.

You should also replace `file.readlines()` `f.readlines()` as `file` is the string of the file path rather than the file object itself.

Comment: im not able to iterate over using this syntax im getting a weird error saying str dosent contain attribute

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Note that I used `os.chdir()` to change the working directory to the directory containing the files. If you files List contain the full path of the files, then you won't need to do this.

```py
import os
#change working directory to the directory containing the files
os.chdir("C:\\Folder1\\Folder Containing files")
files = ['file1.txt','file2.txt','file3.txt']
content = []
for file in files: 
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        content.append(f.readlines()) # note that it's f.readlines() and not file.readlines()
```